# Add private RSS Feed with HTTP BASIC authentication to Feeder?

Tags: applications, authentication

Is there a way to add an RSS Feed that requires BASIC authentication via HTTP to [Feeder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nononsenseapps.feeder.play) app?

I haven't found a way yet and issues in the project's GitLab are disabled, so there is no way to send the request to the man behind the project.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried to include username and password into the RSS URL as specified for URIs? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Example_URIs

Comment: Yes I did, but it doesn't send the authentication header and thus the request to the server fails.